# How do I get an objects height from awakeFromNib to my mainViewController.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, awakefromnib

I programmatically created a `UILable` in a xib file - class of `awakeFromNib`, and I'm trying to get the labels height in the `mainViewController.m`. I tried using an `NSBundle` to load the xib file, but it didn't work. Is there another way I should load it? I need to call `awakFromNib` in `viewDidLoad`.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
    [self.myView addSubview:self.label];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.label.frame.size.height);  // Results: 200.0000
}
```

`mainViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%f", cellVC.label.frame.size.height); // Results: 0.0000
}
```

I need the `NSLog` to display `200`, not `0`.

Comment: What is customCell a subclass of?

Comment: customCell is linked to an xib file which has a cell inside

Comment: In customCell.h what does it inherit from UIView?

Comment: UIView is an object I created in the xib/storyboard file. I then made an IBOutlet naming it myView

Comment: If you add cellVC as a child to your mainViewController does this label show up?

Comment: cellVC is the custom cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70081/discussion-between-skyler-lauren-and-mike-rally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the worst luck loading nibs and issues searching for an easy way to do so. This is what worked for me in the past.

Add this to customCell.m

```
- (id)initWithNib
{
    // where MyCustomView is the name of your nib
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    return self;
}
```

Add this to customCell.h

```
- (id)initWithNib;
```

Now in your view controller do this

```
customCell *cellVC = [[cutsomCell alloc] initWithNib];
```

I found a good link here that uses that example [here](https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/quick-reference-load-a-uiview-created-in-a-nib/)